# Automatic and clean Textwrap?

Tags: python

i'm trying to make a programm that can print multiple playing cards with a different text for each card on it. I want the programm to automatically jump to the next line when a certan length is reached, just like a regular "textbox" would do.
I am making around 120+ cards so i can't be bothered to set the new lines in the string individually with "/n" since i would have to do it by trial and error for every card.
Is there some way to make the programm split a one-lined string individually?
I tried the Textwrap.fill function but its not pretty since some lines are way to long and others too short.

````
    Line1 = Cards_List[indexCD]
    Line1F = Line1.replace('#', '.\n')
    Card_Des = textwrap.fill(text=Line1F, replace_whitespace=False, width=45)
    draw.text((68,840), Card_Des,(0,0,0), font=Small_Font, spacing=2)
    Base.show()
    Base.save(Cards_List[indexCN] + '.png')
indexS = 5
indexCC = 1
indexIcon = 9
indexCN = 2
indexCR = 3
indexCQ = 4
indexCT = 6
indexCA = 7
indexCD = 8```

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3oov.png
````

Comment: it's not clear what you want. put an example of your string and how the result is expected to be.

Comment: When you say "*length*", do you mean number of characters or physical dimensions on the the screen (like pixels, etc.)?

Comment: I posted a picture that may help to convey what im trying to say.
I hope this makes it clearer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are obviously using some graphical interface.  Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").